# How can I make Jmeter use a CSV file but not start at the first line?

Tags: csv, jmeter

I thought I saw this done, but could not find the example.

I have a CSV file with usernames for the login to a site.  This works no problem - each line is read one for each thread/iteration.  But, in the 3rd thread group, there is a place where I call a messaging program.  I would like to use the same names - these are my testbed users - but I don't want to send to the next user in the list and in doing so skip the user for a login.  I would like read from the first line of the csv file for this specific HTTP request.  Is this possible in JMeter?

If not, I would guess I could always simply create another csv file, but I thought I would try something that might have a bit more re-usability later.

Thanks!

Jamie

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as far as I know and as far as I have experienced...